# How to send data in previous screen with help of goBack()?

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack, go-back-n

How to send data in previous screen with help of goBack() ?

`I tried already. For ex:  this.props.navigation.navigate('Login', {name: this.state.name})`

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to pass data to the previous screen then the below works:

Parent screen:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  let navigation = useNavigation();

  const onPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Second', { getData: (x)=>setData(x) }); //<---here you have to pass callback function
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Button
        onPress={onPress}
        title="Add title here"
        color="#841584"
        disabled={false}
      />
      <Text>{data}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Child screen:

```
const Child = ({ route }) => {  //<------here need to take route 
  let navigation = useNavigation();
  const onPress = () => {
    let data = "John";
    route.params.getData(data);   //<-----this way to update.
    navigation.goBack();
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Button
        onPress={onPress}
        title="Add title here"
        color="#841584"
        disabled={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: can we use without route function?

Comment: For that, you need to use a global state management tool. ex. redux